# Animating SVG with GSAP on scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, scroll, gsap

I can't understand how to animate SVG with GSAP framework on scroll. For example I have CSS @keyframes:

```
@keyframes stone {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-360px, -400px) rotate(0);
    }
    25% {
        transform: translate(480px, 200px) rotate(0);
    }
    26% {
        transform: translate(480px, 200px) rotate(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(480px, 400px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    51% {
        transform: translate(480px, 400px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(630px, 480px) rotate(720deg);
    }
}
```

And imagine that start of some div is start point (0%, `offset.top()`) and end of the div is ending point (100%, `offset.top() + div.height()`). How to animate my SVG depending on my scroll state in some div?

I would like to use GSAP for this animations.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with using of TimelineMax:

```
var $ball = $("#ball"),
    tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.to($ball, 2, {x:100,y:20,rotation: 360});
tl.to($ball, 2, {x:200,y:300,rotation: 180});
// etc...

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var content_height = $(document).height();
    var content_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var percentage_value = content_scroll_pos * 100 / (content_height - $(window).height());
    if(percentage_value >= 0 && percentage_value <= 100) {
        tl.tweenTo( tl.duration() * (percentage_value/100) );
        console.log(percentage_value/100);
    }
});
```